# I would like to find R1, R2, and R3 on the diagram shown using L and D

Tags: geometry

[image: Image of intersection of two circles. I need to find R1, R2, and R3 knowing value of L and D. Is there any way to do this or are there too many unknowns?]

Is there any way to find the values of R1, R2, and R3 knowing the value of L and D? Are there too many unknowns in the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what $L$ is supposed to be denoting. Is it just the space between those rings? I.e. $L=R_3-R-2=R_2-R_1$? Or is it the arclength of the cut pieces of the right hand circle?

Comment: It's supposed to be the arclength of the cut pieces on the right hand circle.

Comment: You have to fix one of these $R_i$, then the other two can be deduced from that. The formulae won't be pretty, though.